# How to create a Java program that is type "Application" instead of type "Executable Jar file"

Tags: java, windows, swing, executable-jar

I started working for a company that has some **Java Swing** applications and I just discovered how they make java programs into executable jar files (Export > Executable jar file) and that obviously opens the program, but they have some other files labelled with type: Application instead of "Executable Jar File", and it has the company logo on it. I have no idea how they made the program type Application and add a custom logo and I can't find anything on the internet on how to make that.

[image]

Anyone have any idea? (Both types of files do the same thing but the application one looks more professional)

Comment: Have a look at the file. What is it's actual name, including extension? What are it's contents? You could ask your new colleagues.

Comment: Is this one what you looking for? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: There are a number of "wrapper" utilities which will "wrap" a Jar into a "exe"